# SQLite What platforms does it work on?

Tags: sqlite, serialization, cross-platform, object-persistence, nintendo

I want to use SQLite for object persistence in C++ for making games (I'm thinking of using SDL).  Anyway how cross platform is SQLite?  It works on Windows, Mac, Linux, and Android right?  How about Blackberry, iOS, Nintendo portable and console systems, and Playstation and XBox systems?  Does it work on those systems?, or if not, what does work on those systems.  Is there a better solution than SQLite if I my goal is to be ultra cross-platform?

Also - should I being using plain serialization, such as boost serlialization?  I want to use SQLite because I don't want to use flat files for object storage, because I feel that would be faster for loading objects - especially since I may not always load objects in order.

My idea was to create my own serial abstract base class with a load and save function, and to derive classes from that, and write a custom load and save function for each class to interact with the SQLite database.

I wonder if anyone can suggest any better ideas on that too.

Comment: Why don't you go to SQLite page and look for it there? Too difficult for you?

Comment: Because the site does not say whether or not it supports things like Nintendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is among the most portable code around.  Chances are good it is already running in all of the devices you mention, plus your phones, GPS, car dashboard, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that it works on iOS. As a matter of fact, CoreData Framework relies on it.